# Finding the summation formula for the recurrence relation $T_n=T_{n-1}\;+(n-1)\cdot T_{n-2}\;$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, recurrences

The exponential generating function of this recurrence relation, $T_n=T_{n-1}\;+(n-1)\cdot T_{n-2}\;$, is

$$f(x)=e^{x + \frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Multiplying the exponential generating functions for each term, we get,
$$=\ \sum_{j\geq0}\;\frac{1}{j!}x^j\cdot\sum_{k\geq0}\;\frac{1}{2^kk!}x^{2k}$$
$$=\ \sum_{j,\ \ k\geq0}\;\frac{1}{j!}\cdot\frac{1}{2^kk!}x^{j+2k}$$

Taking $n\ =\ j\ +\ 2k$,
$$=\ \sum_{n-2k,\ \ k\geq0}\;\frac{1}{(n-2k)!}\cdot\frac{1}{2^kk!}x^n$$

What steps can I take from here to find the summation formula for the recurrence relation, i.e.,

$$\;\sum_{n\ge0}\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\frac{n!}{(n-2k)!2^kk!}\Big)\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: You simply change the summation over pairs $(j, k) $ to the summation over pairs $(n, k) $, where $n=j+2k$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740692/about-the-exponential-generating-function-of-the-involutions-of-mathbbs-n .

Comment: @FedorPetrov  $n-2k,\ \ k\geq0$, hence, $0 \leq k \leq n/2$. But what about the $n \geq0$ in the outside summation? I'm aware of the Cauchy product, but I don't know how to use/apply it...

Comment: $n=j+2k\ge 0$ without doubts, and, vice versa, if $n\ge 0$ and $0\le k\le n/2$, then $j:=n-2k$ is non-negative.

Comment: Your latter sum is of course $f(x)$. So, what is your question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your latter sum,
   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!},$$
   is just $f(x)=e^{x+x^2/2}$, as shown in your own post, where
   $$a_n:=T_n=\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\frac{n!}{(n-2k)!2^k k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom n{2k}\frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}.\tag{1}$$
2. A closed-form expression for $a_n$ apparently does not exist. Anyway, Mathematica does not know it:

[image]

3. However, one may note that your function $f$ is the moment generating function of the normal distribution with mean $1$ and variance $1$. So, if $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, then
   $$a_n=E(Z+1)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj EZ^j=\sum_{0\le k\le n/2}\binom n{2k} EZ^{2k},$$
   whence (1) follows. The recurrence relation $a_n=(n-1)a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}$ also follows, by writing
   $$E(Z+1)^n=EZ(Z+1)^{n-1}+E(Z+1)^{n-1}$$
   and taking the first of the latter two integrals by parts.

Mathematica can only give the trivial answer for $E(Z+1)^n$:
[image]

Comment: Also, $a_n$ is the total number of matchings of all sizes in the complete graph $K_n$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay : Thank you for your comment. Do you know if a closed-form expression for this number (or the impossibility of having such a form) is known? A lot about $a_n$ is on the OEIS page https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+10%2C+26%2C+76%2C+232%2C+764%2C+2620%2C+9496&language=english&go=Search

Comment: @IosifPinelis, as I noted in my answer prior to your comment, A000085 contains much info, including the hypergeometric function characterization. Mathematicians working in this area either contribute to this entry or have their notes referenced in the OEIS by others more often than not. As for the meaning of closed form, what do you mean precisely? $b^n$?

Comment: @TomCopeland : Thank you for your comment. Sorry, I did not notice your OEIS link to this sequence. As for the meaning of closed-form, I guess an expression in terms of the gamma function and the elementary functions, not involving a general hypergeometric function, would be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The [probabilist's Hermite polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) (OEIS [A066325](https://oeis.org/A066325)) $He_n(x)$ have the e.g.f.

$$e^{He.(t)x} = e^{xt} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} = e^{xt} e^{h.x} = e^{(h.+ t)x}$$

where

$$He_n(t) = (h. + t)^n =\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} h_k t^{n-k}$$

with

$$h_n = \cos(\frac{\pi n}{2}) \frac{n!}{(n/2)!} 2^{-n/2}.$$

Consequently,

$$f(x) = e^{a.x} = e^{x+ x^2/2}$$

$$= e^{-He(i)ix},$$

so

$$a_n = (-i)^n He_n(i) = \hat{He}_n(1),$$

where $\hat{H}_n(x)$ are the row polynomials of [A099174](https://oeis.org/A099174) with row sums, $a_n$, the sequence OEIS [A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085) with extensive characterizations.

Comment: Of additional interest: on Hermite integrals by Anshelevich  http://see-math.math.tamu.edu/~manshel/papers/Hermite-integrals.pdf